# Custom Search Component in Digital Experiences Site disappears in occasionally (not happened frequently)

Tags: search, site.com

**Custom Search Component in Digital Experiences Site disappears in occasionally (not happened frequently), and this issue never happened in Chrome Incognito Window (only happened in Chrome normal window with cache enabled).**

**And when this issue reported by our end users, we re-publish the site without changing any code or configurations the issue resolved temporary， but unfortunately some time later the issue will come up again**.

**We built a Custom Search Component and added it to the site.**
[image]

[image]

**The page with Custom Search Component appearing:**
[image]

**The page with Custom Search Component disappearing:**
[image]